# Import .a and .h to Project

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ programming. I'm given a .a file, a .h file, a .lib and some .dll files, and would like to study them, but I have no idea on how to work with them. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015. Please tell as detail as possible. Many thanks. ^^

Comment: As of now, your question is too broad. Please make an effort to go through google for usage and narrow down your followup questions to specifics..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to learn things about how to build a project in C++ ? For example,

1. **compile** your source codes(.cpp) with some headers(.h).
2. **link** them with some libraries(.a, .so).

If this is the case, you can try the following references:

- Managing Projects with GNU Make, 3rd edition, Robert Mecklenburg, O'REILLY.
- [gcc/g++ command options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_3.html)
- [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

BTW, for the book, you only need to read **Part I**. Then you'll understand lots of secrets behind **Building a project**.